# seeds to generate reproducible random numbers

Tags: r, seed

I am trying to get reproducible results. I assign random numbers to each entry 1 to 100 in a data frame. How do I get the same number from a random number generator?

```
seed <- 1

seed = as.integer(Sys.time())
set.seed(seed)


ID <- 1:100
x <- as.integer(rnorm(100,50,20))

y <- as.integer(rnorm(100,50,20)) 

agent <- as.matrix(cbind(ID,x,y))
```

This is how I tried it without success.

Comment: You will get the same results if you set `seed` as the same value immediately before generating the random numbers.  But your second line sets it to a different value each time you run it.

Comment: You could [set the seed multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324208/weird-behavior-of-using-set-seed-multiple-times/45324286#45324286), although here just `as.matrix(cbind(ID,x,x))` could also work?

Comment: Please see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380096/set-seed-with-r-2-15-2

Comment: Thanks everyone

So when I put

ID <- 1:100
set.seed(12345)
x <- as.integer(rnorm(100,50,20))
set.seed(12345)
y <- as.integer(rnorm(100,50,20)) 

agent <- as.matrix(cbind(ID,x,y))

I always get the same results for agent